# Android app creation with Eclipse and SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have been trying to figure this out to compile source code for 2 weeks now, i keep getting errors. I tried 10 different combinations of eclipse and the sdk

I read the step by step things and still cant figure it out.

I created an app on buzztouch.com and downloaded the source code, all i have to do is compile it should be simple but no.

so step one. 
could someone give a direct link to an eclipse version that works with the windows SDK found here
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?
I have been installing eclipse first is the right way to do it, should i download and install the sdk first? or does it just not make a difference?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am outlining some of the steps:

1. Download JDK 6 from [Sun Microsystems Website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), click on **Download JDK** button from *JDK 6 Update 22 (JDK or JRE)* section.
2. Download **Eclipse Helios (not recommended but works for me) IDE** for Java Developers, 99 MB from [Eclipse Website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), choose appropriate version viz. 32 bit / 64 bit system.
3. Install ADT 0.9.9 Eclipse plug-in. Here is the instruction [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).
4. Install Android SDK, download from [Official Developer Website](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r07-windows.zip). You can find Instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

As you have mentioned your case, you must have been following the same procedure I suppose, but I would suggest delete everything and start freshly. Do a YouTube video search for *"Getting Started with Android Development"* or may be *Installing Android SDK* for more help.

Hope this helps,
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Install Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. I used version 3.5 and 3.6 for both Windows and Ubuntu.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-jee-galileo-SR1-win32.zip

Comment: Google warns against using the ADT plugin with Eclipse 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Eclipse Classic Indigo (latest version). I ran into similar issues with installing the SDK with Eclipse, I found that I had to install the Android SDK first and download at least one platform SDK Tools (as well as the latest JDK). Then open up Eclipse, go to options and "Check for updates", allow it to run and install all updates. Go to the "install new software" section and look at the "Additional Sites" section, enable the "GEF" site and download the Gef SDK.

Download the ADT Archive (.zip) file off the Android website. Go to Eclipse "Install New Software" click add and then go to Archive. Select the file and then install the Android plugin. This should be all you require to get ADT all setup with Eclipse.